# You dont have permission to access

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

desde hace un tiempo hice webscraping con selenium y c# a la página de soriana ya que en la empresa en que trabajo es necesario descargar la relación de los productos que nos consumen y el los ultimos 2 meses me aparece esto:
[image: acceso denegado]

El programa se loguea y busca los pedidos de cierto periodo y los descarga, lo malo que son cientos casi miles por eso se automatizo, a alguien le ha pasado algo similar con esta página u otra? me recomiendan otra cosa para hacer esa funcion?

Comment: Es nada práctico que el título de tu pregunta diga *pedidos empresa X*, no dice nada, en su lugar mejor coloca el mensaje de error que obtienes, te recomiendo leas [ask]

Comment: parece que bloquearon tu ip... no se cual seria tu pregunta.. es si la pagina de la cual queres sacar informacion anda?

Comment: @BetaM, gracias por la observación, es mi primer pregunta e intente hacerla bien, la próxima no me pasa.

Comment: @gbianchi si me puedo loguear manualmente y realizar toda la operación, pero cuando se abre desde el controlador del selenium cuando me logueo sale ese mensaje y no deja avanzar

Comment: Tu IP está bloqueada, webscrapping es mal visto por algunas personas, tu solución es usar proxys, mucho mejor si son residenciales

Comment: Gracias @Daniel, lo pruebo